# Collection admin role not found in IAM for Azure purview

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-purview

To "add a collection", I think I need to have "collection admin" role in Azure purview. However, when I am going to Azure purview account and clicks on "Access control(IAM)" -> "role assignments", I don't see "collection admin".

My question is, where can I see "collection admin"? Is it only from Azure Purview Studio?

Also, I can see I have access to a access package, and this access package has security group added as "resource role" (that is, "`+Add resource roles`" ) and I'm a member of the security group as "contributor eligible". The security group is created for Azure Purview.

Another question is, if I am a member of "Azure purview contributor eligible" security group, then why I'm not considered as "collection admin" and why "add a collection (`+ Add a collection`) is greyed out for me?

Note, I referred this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/catalog-permissions) but unable to get a clear idea. How can I make `+Add a collection` enabled for me?

Answer (score 1):

> To "add a collection", I think I need to have "collection admin" role
> in Azure purview. However, when I am going to Azure purview account
> and clicks on "Access control(IAM)" -> "role assignments", I don't see
> "collection admin".
>
> My question is, where can i see "collection admin"? Is it only from
> Azure Purview Studio?
> My another question is, if I am a member of "Azure purview contributor
> eligible" security group, then why I'm not considered as "collection
> admin" and why "add a collection (+ Add a collection) is greyed out
> for me?

`Collection Admin` is a permission/role for Azure Purview which can be only found from `Azure Purview studio`. As mentioned in this [`Microsoft Document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-create-and-manage-collections#check-permissions) on how to create/manage Collections in Azure purview , you need to have `Collection Admin Role` assigned to you in order to perform operations related to Collection.

> How can I make +Add a collection enabled for me?

As the `Azure purview contributor eligible` Security group is not added in collection Admin role assignment , you will have to add it by following the above shared Microsoft document or reach out to the admin to grant you the collection admin permission so that you can create/manage collections.

Comment: Hi AnsumanBal-MT: Thanks for the link and reply. Could you please tell me how can I check any other user activity (login activity) logs? And, from where should I check them?

Comment: Also, if the activity logs can be collected from Azure Purview account, then what does in 
 the  column "operation name" -> value as "List keys on the account resource" means?